# Finding certain characters in the middle of the word using Regex UNIX

Tags: regex, linux, unix

I need to create a regex that matches cat in 'My cat is brown', but not in category or bobcat. then i need to create another regex that matches cat in staccato, but not in any of the three previous.

This is a an assignment i'm working on. I got the first part to work i used / .at/ and found cat but i'm stuck on the second part, i can't figure out how to find just cat in staccato. The best i could do is cat\o and find 'cato' or [c].at and find ccat.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: You can use word boundaries `\b` `\B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\bcat\b` will match 'My cat is brown', but not 'category', 'bobcat' or 'staccato'

`\Bcat\B` will match 'staccato', but not 'My cat is brown', 'category' or 'bobcat'

Matching (or not-matching) word boundaries is the key to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

using grep:

```
echo "staccato" | grep -o "cat"
#prints "cat"
```

Also works for 'My cat is brown':

```
echo "My cat is brown" | grep -o "cat"
#prints "cat"
```